# How to get a Sweave pdf into a different directory

Tags: r, pdf, directory, latex, sweave

In Ubuntu, suppose in `/home/folder1` I have `test.Rnw`. To generate a `pdf` I will go (assuming this directory is my `getwd`) within my `R` console:

```
Sweave(test.Rnw)
texi2pdf(test.tex)
```

However, my objective is to have the `pdf` save in another existing folder called `/home/folder2`. How do I compile the `.Rnw` (which is to remain in `/home/folder1`) and the resulting `.tex` (don't care which folder this gets into) such that the `pdf` ends up in `/home/folder2`?

It seems that I want to interfere with either the arguments in `Sweave(...)` or `texi2pdf(...)` but haven't found a parameter I can toggle to set export directory.

Answer (score 3):

It is simpler to use `knitr` package:

```
knit2pdf(input=/home/folder1/test.Rnw, 
         output =/home/folder2/test.pdf)
```

Another option is to use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html) :

```
pandoc -f latex /home/folder1/test.tex -s -o /home/folder2/test.pdf
```

Comment: If an `Rnw` file works with `Sweave` does it as a consequence also necessarily work with `knitr`?

Comment: @user2763361 I think so. `knitr ≈ Sweave + cacheSweave + ...some others packages` in a single package.

Comment: I can also recommend using the knitr package since it is pretty straight forward.